# JSF2.0 primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need your help on JSF2. I made a datatable to list data items from database. I want to select an item from that list an print it on an edit dialog. The problem is that the item's data is'nt shown on that dialog. Here is JSF code used to generate it:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{airportController.items}" var="item" style="border: 0px;">
    <f:facet name="header">Airports</f:facet>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.airportId}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
        <p:commandButton title="View" value="" update=":airportForm:airportEditForm" icon="edit_icon.gif"oncomplete="editAirportDlg.show();">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{airportController.selected}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" onclick="createAirportDgl.show();"/>    
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="airportEditForm" widgetVar="editAirportDlg" modal="false"  header="Modifier" rendered="true" resizable="false">
    <h:panelGrid id="airportDisplay" columns="2" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"   rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <h:outputText value="Pays"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.country}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Ville"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.city}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Nom"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.name}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Addresse"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.hqAddress}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Valider" action="#{airportController.update()}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

All that is put all together in the index.xhtml page.
I don't know what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you send the whole xhtml content? This could be a validation problem. Try to use process="@this" on the commandButton and update the airportDisplay instead.

```
<p:commandButton title="View" value=""
    update=":airportForm:airportDisplay"
    icon="edit_icon.gif"oncomplete="editAirportDlg.show();" process="@this">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{airportController.selected}"/> 
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put everything i.e your `datatable` and `dialog` inside `h:form` with id and then

on edit button click update your dialog with respect to grid id like `:form:airportDisplay` also shown in below.

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000"/>  


    <p:dataTable value="#{airportController.items}" var="item" style="border: 0px;">
    <f:facet name="header">Airports</f:facet>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.airportId}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
        <p:commandButton title="View" value="" update=":form:airportDisplay" icon="edit_icon.gif"oncomplete="editAirportDlg.show();">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{airportController.selected}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" onclick="createAirportDgl.show();"/>    
</p:dataTable>


    <p:dialog id="airportEditForm" widgetVar="editAirportDlg" modal="false"  header="Modifier" rendered="true" resizable="false">
    <h:panelGrid id="airportDisplay" columns="2" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"   rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <h:outputText value="Pays"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.country}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Ville"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.city}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Nom"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.name}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Addresse"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.hqAddress}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Valider" action="#{airportController.update()}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>     



        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, here is page content,

**index.xhtml**

> ```
> <ui:define name="title">
>     Airports
> </ui:define>
>
> <ui:define name="header">
>     header
> </ui:define>
>
> <ui:define name="menu">
>     menu
> </ui:define>
>
> <ui:define name="content">
>     <h:form id="airportForm">
>         <ui:include src="list.xhtml"/>
>         <ui:include src="edit.xhtml"/>
>         <ui:include src="create.xhtml"/>
>     </h:form>
> </ui:define> </ui:composition>
> ```

**list.xhtml**

> ```
> <p:dataTable value="#{airportController.items}" var="item" style="border: 0px;" >paginator="true"
>              rowKey="#{item.airportId}" selection="#{airportController.selected}" >selectionMode="single"
> ```
>
> sortBy="#{item.airportId}">
>           Airports
>           
>               ID
>               
>           
>           
>                   Nom
>                   
>           
>           
>               Pays
>               
>           
>           
>               Ville
>               
>           
>           
>               Addesse
>               
>           
>           
>               onclick="editAirportDlg.show();"/>
>
> > update=":airportForm:airportCreateForm"
> >     onclick="createAirportDgl.show();"/>

**edit.xhtml**

> ```
> <p:dialog widgetVar="editAirportDlg" modal="false" 
>           header="Modifier" rendered="true" resizable="false">
>     <h:form id="airportEditForm">
>     <h:panelGrid columns="2">
>         <h:outputText value="Pays :"/>
>         <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.country}"/>
>         <h:outputText value="Ville: "/>
>         <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.city}"/>
>         <h:outputText value="Nom: "/>
>         <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.name}"/>
>         <h:outputText value="Addresse: "/>
>         <p:inputText value="#{airportController.selected.hqAddress}"/>
>         <f:facet name="footer">
>             <p:commandButton value="Valider" icon="ui-icon-disk" action=" {airportController.update()}"/>
>         </f:facet>
>     </h:panelGrid>
>     </h:form>
> </p:dialog> </ui:composition>
> ```